# How to use socket in Python as a context manager?

Tags: python, sockets, contextmanager

It seems like it would be only natural to do something like:

```
with socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
```

but Python doesn't implement a context manager for socket. Can I easily use it as a context manager, and if so, how?

Comment: "Why" questions are in general not good questions for SO. Perhaps you can rewrite this into "how"? :-)

Comment: @msw: No. That's just a why-question in disguise. A good question is "How do I use a socket as a context manager?". The current question I could correctly answer with. "It does" or "No", or "Yes". Not very helpful.

Comment: @msw: Firstly, this is just more confirmation that "why" questions are bad, since they can trigger an infinite "why not" descent into hell. :-) Secondly,  I think you misunderstand what context managers are. The answer "a socket is not like a file" doesn't make any sense as an answer to the "why" question in this case. It's completely irrelevant that it is not like a file. Context managers are not just for files.

Comment: @msw: I didn't alter the meaning, I made it a good question.

Comment: @msw: Note that closing is really a temporary state; improve the question and it can be reopened again. Improving the question *before* it is closed is a better idea still.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The `socket` module is fairly low-level, giving you almost direct access to the C library functionality.

You can always use the [`contextlib.contextmanager` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) to build your own:

```
import socket
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def socketcontext(*args, **kw):
    s = socket.socket(*args, **kw)
    try:
        yield s
    finally:
        s.close()

with socketcontext(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
```

or use [`contextlib.closing()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) to achieve the same effect:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)) as s:
```

but the `contextmanager()` decorator gives you the opportunity to do other things with the socket first.

Python 3.x does make `socket()` a context manager, but the documentation wasn't updated to reflect this [until well into the Python 3.5 cycle, in 2016](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e37fc18b3c0d5fe13d75f37d9ae9c4387a46ee3d). See the [`socket` class](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e57c8a90b2df/Lib/socket.py#l87) in the source code, which adds `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

Comment: the Python3 `with`/`as` seems very useful, I can't think of any reason to leave this out of the docs, would you happen to know why it's not in there?

Comment: @RyanHaining: The [patch submitter](http://bugs.python.org/issue9794) merely forgot to document it properly.

Comment: @RyanHaining: The patch did update [`socket.create_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) but it's kinda hidden.

Comment: what is meant by "first" where it says "gives you the opportunity to do other things with the socket first"? Seems to me that the custom context manager (i.e. socketcontext) allows one to do exactly the same things as contextlib.closing. What is the difference??

Comment: @allyourcode: `contextlib.closing()` will only call `close` on the socket. A custom context manager could, say,  bind to an open port, set a timeout or other socket options first, or send out a protocol-specific closing packet or some such when exiting the context.

Comment: This needs to be `with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)) as s:`

Comment: @Lunulata: indeed; I corrected the other reference too. Thanks!

Comment: The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects) actually states explicit support for the context manager protocol. Not sure if it did back in '13, but at least now it does.

Comment: @MikeVe: it didn't in but 2013. Note that in 2014 we discussed this in the comments here, how the patch submitter forgot to update the docs. The docs were eventually fixed [in 2016](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e37fc18b3c0d5fe13d75f37d9ae9c4387a46ee3d).

Answer (score 36):

The socket module is just a wrapper around the BSD socket interface. It's low-level, and does not really attempt to provide you with a handy or easy to use Pythonic API. You may want to use something higher-level.

That said, it does in fact implement a context manager:

```
>>> with socket.socket() as s:
...   print(s)
... 
<socket.socket object, fd=3, family=2, type=1, proto=0>
```

But you need to use Python 3.

For Python 2 compatibility you can use `contextlib`.

```
from contextlib import closing
import socket

with closing(socket.socket()) as s:
    print s
```

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look on following snippets, for both TCP and UDP sockets

```
import socket
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def tcp_connection_to(*args, **kwargs):
    s = socket.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
    yield s
    s.close()


@contextmanager
def udp_connection():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    yield s
    s.close()
```

So that you can use them in following way:

```
MY_SERVER = ('localhost', 5000)   # Yes, we need tuple here
some_data = bytes("Hello.")

with tcp_connection_to(MY_SERVER) as conn:
    conn.send(some_data)

with udp_connection() as conn:
    conn.sendto(some_data, MY_SERVER)
```

I've also tried to emphasise the difference in behaviour and approach to term 'connection' between TCP  and UDP in method names.